# getppid return wrong parent's pid

Tags: linux, process, fork, parent, pid

I have to build process tree:

[Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h20Ok.png)

I used `fork` command to do it, but every process show same (wrong) ppid: **1528** which is not their parent's pid. On windows i used cLions compiler and it works fine (apart of I), but the tree doesnt appear. On linux i use gcc -o and there is invalid result and as well, no process tree.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

char buf[40];
sprintf(buf, "pstree -c %d", getpid());

int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k;

printf("A: Parent of all: %d\n", getpid());
a = fork();

    if (a == 0) {
    printf("B: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // B
    b = fork();

    if (b == 0) {
        printf("D: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // D
        d = fork();
        if (d == 0) {
            printf("G: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // G
        }
        else {
            d = fork();
            if(d==0) {
                printf("H: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // H
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        b = fork();
        if (b == 0) {
            printf("E: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // E
            e=fork();
            if(e==0){
                printf("I: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // I
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    a = fork();
    if (a == 0) {
        printf("C: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // C
        c=fork();
        if(c==0){
            printf("F: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // F
            f=fork();
            if(f==0){
                printf("J: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // J
            }
            else{
                f=fork();
                if(f==0){
                    system(buf);
                    //printf("K: My pid: %d, parent id: %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); // K
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Result on windows:

```
A: Parent of all: 908
B: My pid: 910, parent id: 908
C: My pid: 911, parent id: 908
D: My pid: 912, parent id: 910
F: My pid: 913, parent id: 911
G: My pid: 914, parent id: 912
E: My pid: 915, parent id: 910
J: My pid: 916, parent id: 913
H: My pid: 917, parent id: 912
I: My pid: 919, parent id: 1
sh: pstree: command not found
```

Result on linux:

```
A: Parent of all: 17793
C: My pid: 17795, parent id: 1528
B: My pid: 17794, parent id: 1528
F: My pid: 17796, parent id: 1528
J: My pid: 17798, parent id: 1528
K: My pid: 17799, parent id: 1528
D: My pid: 17797, parent id: 1528
H: My pid: 17804, parent id: 1528
G: My pid: 17803, parent id: 1528
E: My pid: 17802, parent id: 1528
I: My pid: 17805, parent id: 1528
```

I have no idea what should i add or change to make it works.

Comment: I can't reproduce, on Linux I get e. g. `A: Parent of all: 31982
B: My pid: 31983, parent id: 31982
C: My pid: 31984, parent id: 31982
F: My pid: 31985, parent id: 31984
E: My pid: 31987, parent id: 1
J: My pid: 31988, parent id: 31985
D: My pid: 31986, parent id: 1
I: My pid: 31990, parent id: 31987
G: My pid: 31991, parent id: 31986
H: My pid: 31993, parent id: 1
`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what should i add or change to make it works.

The reason why *the tree doesnt appear* is that the `Parent of all` for which the *process tree* is requested has already ended by the time process K gets to execute the `system(buf)` command. To prevent the parent from disappearing early, insert

```
    while (wait(NULL) > 0) ;
```

as the last executable line in the program (at the end of `main`).